# In two subversion repositories (same machine), can I have different usernames with no password prompting?

Tags: caching, svn, passwords

I host 2 subversion repositories on localhost, `repoA` and `repoB`, which I checkout as `svn://localhost/repo-name`. Can I have a different username in each repository with no password prompts? For instance, can I be `smith` in `repoA` and `jones` in `repoB`, transparently? "Transparent" means typing `svn commit` without `--username` for both repos, and both passwords cached.

An idealized example:

```
$ svn checkout svn:.... repoA --username smith --password xxxxxx
$ svn checkout svn:.... repoB --username jones --password yyyyyy

$ cd repoA
(edit a file)
$ svn commit -m"edited a file in repoA as smith"
(succeeds without any password prompt)

$ cd ../repoB
(edit a file)
$ svn commit -m"edited a file in repoB as jones"
(succeeds without any password prompt)
```

Is this possible, or can I have only 1 locally cached subversion password at a time? Thank you very much.

Comment: What errors do you get when doing as you describe? Does the password have to be cached locally? You could set Subversion up to use a password manager which would (presumably) offer more features. Using SSH might also be an option.